# Rails delayed job runs twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, rails-activejob

I added the `delayed_job` gem and I created a simple ActiveJob. I am inserting record to the DB after my job run. When I check the table I am seeing 2 records. And I am seeing the following lines in my console.

```
[Worker(host:k pid:4962)] Job SimpleJob (id=9305) (queue=Default) RUNNING
[Worker(host:k pid:4962)] Job SimpleJob (id=9305) (queue=Default) COMPLETED after 0.7371
[Worker(host:k pid:4962)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=9306) (queue=Default) RUNNING
[Worker(host:k pid:4962)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=9306) (queue=Default) COMPLETED after 0.5055
[Worker(host:k pid:4962)] 2 jobs processed at 1.5728 j/s, 0 failed
```

Why is my job running twice? How can I fix that?

**Edit:** The following code is my ActiveJob code. I added a `SimpleJob.schedule!` line in `config/initializers/job_initializars.rb` for first start.

```
class SimpleJob < ActiveJob::Base

include Delayed::RecurringJob
  run_every 1.minute
  queue 'Default'

  def perform
    begin   
      Vehicle.where(number_plate: lo."12345" ).update_all(:longitude => "47", :latitude => "33")

    rescue => ex
      Delayed::Worker.logger.info "---------------->" +  ex.message
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: How are you calling the job?

Comment: It's very hard to debug a verbal description of your code :) can you please edit your question and add all the relevant code snippets? Your ActiveJob, the scheduler, some example data? etc

Comment: @Pablo 1+1 :)))

Comment: sorry for missing information, I edited my question, thanks